# Are two map iterators that point to the same item guaranteed to be equal?

Tags: c++, iterator, standard-library

I have a `map` object to which I want to insert a new element. After doing this, I want to make sure that this newly inserted element was inserted **at the end**. To do this, I have devised the following way:

```
map<T1,T2> m;
//populate m
auto ret_pair = m.insert({o1,o2}); //o1,o2 objects of types T1,T2

auto end = m.cend();
--end;
if (ret_pair.first != end) //<-- this worries me
  throw runtime_error("boom");
```

The line where I compare the two iterators worries me, because I'm not sure if I can rely on these different iterators to be the same, even if the point to the same thing.

What do you think? Why would this (not) work?

Comment: I am surprised Dennis Ritchie wouldn't know the answer to this.

Comment: I don't get the point of the question. If you're going to insist on inserting elements in the order in which the map will place them, why do you need the overhead of having the map sort the elements? Just stuff the elements into a `vector` or a `deque`.

Comment: @0A0D He's more of a C guy anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators which point to the same element compare equal. If they didn't, every algorithm in the standard library would break.

So yes, your code is fine.